# How can I read the checkbox?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I read the automatically generated checkboxes and if a checkbox has the value "True" save the name of the checkbox to an automatically generated variable.

Target of the macro:
For the single saving of serial letters I want the user to be able to define the name of the different documents. Therefore I created a UserForm on which all possible names are listed (all columns in Excel). For example, if a person selects two columns (first and last name), he or she will use the content of this column for saving.

Example:
First and last name
--> Liam_Smith.pdf
--> Emma_Johnson.pdf

**important code part**

```
'################################################ --> Hauptteil / Userform Name

    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge

            Dim myLabel As Object
            Dim myCheckBox As Object
            Dim y As Integer
            Dim ColumnCount As Integer
            Dim CaptionValue As String
            Load UserForm3


            'ColumnCount = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
            ColumnCount = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.FieldNames.Count
            'MsgBox (ColumnCount)

            For y = 1 To ColumnCount
            CaptionValue = (ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields(y).Name)

            Set myCheckBox = UserForm3.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "Test" & 1, True)
                With myCheckBox
                    .Name = "myCheckBox" & y
                    .Left = 24
                    .Top = (17.5 + (y * 20))
                End With

            Set myLabel = UserForm3.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Test" & 1, True)
                With myLabel
                .Caption = (CaptionValue)
                .Left = 54
                .Top = (20 + (y * 20))
                .Width = 50
                .Height = 12
            End With
            Next y

            Load UserForm3
            UserForm3.Show

    '################################################ --> CheckBox auswertung

        'For y = 1 To ColumnCount
            'If UserForm3.CheckBox.Value = True Then
                'MsgBox "True"
            'Else
                'MsgBox "False"
            'End If
```

**entire code:**

```
Sub SerienbriefOneDoc()
'
' SerienbriefOneDoc Makro
'
'
Dim Dateiname As String
Dim LetzterRec As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Visible = False


'################################################ --> Speicherort

'Variable declaration
Dim sFolderName As String
Dim sDesktopPath As String, sFolderPath As String

'Find Desktop path location
sDesktopPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"

'Define folder name to create on the desktop
sFolderName = "Serienbrief"

'Folder Path
sFolderPath = sDesktopPath & sFolderName

'Create FSO Object
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Check Specified Folder exists or not
If oFSO.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
    'If folder is available on the desktop
    MsgBox "Der angegebene Ordner existiert bereits auf dem Desktop!", vbInformation, "VBAF1"
    GoTo PDFsave
Else
    'Create Folder
    MkDir sFolderPath

    'Diplay messafe on the screen
    MsgBox "Ordner erstellt : " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & sFolderPath, vbInformation, "VBAF1"
End If


'################################################ --> Speicherort UserForm


'################################################ --> Makro einstellungen

PDFsave:

Dim isUpdating As Boolean
isUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating

'we need ScreenUpdating toggled on to do this:
If Not isUpdating Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'if msg is empty, status goes to "Ready"
Application.StatusBar = msg

'make sure the update gets displayed (we might be in a tight loop)
DoEvents

'if ScreenUpdating was off, toggle it back off:
Application.ScreenUpdating = isUpdating

 ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord
 LetzterRec = Word.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
 ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord

'################################################ --> Hauptteil / Userform Name

With ActiveDocument.MailMerge

        Dim myLabel As Object
        Dim myCheckBox As Object
        Dim y As Integer
        Dim ColumnCount As Integer
        Dim CaptionValue As String
        Load UserForm3


        'ColumnCount = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
        ColumnCount = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.FieldNames.Count
        'MsgBox (ColumnCount)

        For y = 1 To ColumnCount
        CaptionValue = (ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields(y).Name)

        Set myCheckBox = UserForm3.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "Test" & 1, True)
            With myCheckBox
                .Name = "myCheckBox" & y
                .Left = 24
                .Top = (17.5 + (y * 20))
            End With

        Set myLabel = UserForm3.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Test" & 1, True)
            With myLabel
            .Caption = (CaptionValue)
            .Left = 54
            .Top = (20 + (y * 20))
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 12
        End With
        Next y

        Load UserForm3
        UserForm3.Show

'################################################ --> CheckBox auswertung

    'For y = 1 To ColumnCount
        'If UserForm3.CheckBox.Value = True Then
            'MsgBox "True"
        'Else
            'MsgBox "False"
        'End If

'################################################ --> Progressbar

     'MsgBox (.DataSource.RecordCount)
     .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord


      Dim RecordCount As Integer
      Dim i As Integer, percent As Integer, ActiveDoc As Integer, ActivePercent As Integer
      Dim widthUpdate As Double, j As Double
      UserForm2.Label1.BackColor = &HFF00&
      percent = 100
      UserForm2.Label1.Width = 0
      RecordCount = .DataSource.RecordCount
      ActiveDoc = .DataSource.ActiveRecord
      i = 1

     Do
        i = i + 1
        j = i * percent / RecordCount
        widthUpdate = j * 2
        ActivePercent = j
        UserForm2.Label1.Width = widthUpdate
        UserForm2.Label2.Caption = ActivePercent & "% Complete"

         If .DataSource.ActiveRecord > 0 Then                                                                           
'Prueft ob es mehrere Seiten fuer den Serienbrief gibt
            If RecordCount <> "0" Then                                                                                  
'zaehlt die Anzahl Datensaetz in der Spalte "Name"
                 .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                 .SuppressBlankLines = True

                    If Dir(sFolderPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then                                                         
'prueft ob es das Verzeichnis gibt.
                    Else
                        MsgBox "Verzeichnis existiert nicht"                                                            
'Fehlermeldung falls das Verzeichniss nicht existiert
                    End If
                 With .DataSource
                     .FirstRecord = .ActiveRecord
                     .LastRecord = .ActiveRecord
                        dname = sFolderPath & "\" & Name1 & "_" & Name2 & ".pdf"                                        
'erstellt eine Variable mit dem Pfad und dem Namen
                 End With
                    .Execute Pause:=False
                    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=dname, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF                                     
'benennt die Datei und aendert das Dateiformat auf PDF
                    ActiveDocument.Close False                                                                          
'schliesst das Fenster
             End If
           End If
         If .DataSource.ActiveRecord < LetzterRec Then                                                                  
'prueft ob es noch eine Seite gibt im Serienbrief
             .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord                                                                    
'nimmt die naechste Seite des Serienbriefes
         Else
             Exit Do                                                                                                    
'wenn es keine Seite im Serienbrief mehr gibt wird die Schleife beendet
         End If
        UserForm2.Show (0)
        Load UserForm2
        DoEvents
        UserForm2.Repaint
     Loop
     Unload UserForm2
 End With

 Application.Visible = True
 Application.StatusBar = False
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = sBar
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**My UserForm**

1. [UserForm_V1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlZpL.png)
2. [UserVorm_V2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEgus.png)
3. [Excel_Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySd4T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the name of the `CheckBox` to a variable, you can do something like:

```
Dim myCheckboxName as string
Dim Ctrl as Control

For each Ctrl in <UserForm>.MSForms.Controls
    If TypeName(Ctrl) = "CheckBox" then
        If Ctrl.Value = True Then
            myCheckboxName = Ctrl.Name
        End If
    End If
Next Ctrl
```

Keep in mind to replace  with a reference to your form, this will loop through *all* controls on your userform so if more than 1 checkbox is checked, this will end up storing the last checked one that is accessed in the loop - but this gives you an idea of how to find the checked on and assign it's name to a variable.

I'd suggest using the caption on the `CheckBox` rather than a separate `Label` to make things a lot easier to reference and locate in your code. Something like:

```
Set myCheckBox = UserForm3.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "Test" & 1, True)
    With myCheckBox
        .Name = "myCheckBox" & y
        .Caption = CaptionValue '<~~
        .Left = 24
        .Top = (17.5 + (y * 20))
    End With
```

Then you can locate which of the `CheckBox` are checked later on and directly refer to it's caption rather than trying to work out a good way to name/apply your labels to locate them once you have found the corrosponding checkbox that is checked.

Something like:

```
With UserForm3.CheckBox
    For y = 1 To ColumnCount
        If .Value = True Then
            MsgBox .Caption & " is checked."
        Else
            MsgBox .Caption & " is not checked."
        End If
    Next y
End with
```

I don't see what you intend to use the caption for in your code so I've used your test loop in the example here.

You can apply the same principal if you want to keep it how it is an use a `CheckBox` and a separate `Label` for the caption, but you will need to work out a good way to be able to reference the correct `Label.Caption` when you find the checked `CheckBox` like naming them with the same number and checking the `.Name` property matches the same number by using the `Mid()` function or something like that.